# How to copy an integer variable to a static variable in python?

Tags: python, static, pygame

I wanted to have a marker icon appear at the position of the cursor and stay there, but I have been running through the issue of the marker icon always following the position of the cursor and disappearing when the Z key is not pressed down

Since I already know that the issue is that the pin and cursor position is updating with every frame, I wanted to ask how I can make the marker icon static, so that it would be placed in that one location and wouldn't move around with the cursor.

Here is my code for marker placement:

```
def drop_mark(self, screen, cursorx, cursory):
        Mark = pygame.image.load("Pin.Png").convert_alpha()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_z]:
            markx = cursorx
            marky = cursory
            screen.blit(Mark, (markx, marky))
```

And Here is the use of the function in the code:

```
def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((848, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    CursorSprite = pygame.image.load("WorldMapReticle.png").convert_alpha()
    WorldMapCursor = cursor(CursorSprite, 0, 0)
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        createScreen(screen)
        WorldMapCursor.render(screen)
        WorldMapCursor.move_right()
        WorldMapCursor.move_left()
        WorldMapCursor.move_down()
        WorldMapCursor.move_up()
        WorldMapCursor.drop_mark(screen, WorldMapCursor.x, WorldMapCursor.y)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining `markx` and `marky` in the function, all you need to do is define them out of the function. Then update those variables once. Personally, i wouldn't put the `if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_z]:` in the function but to do it this way i would do the following:

```
markx = 0
marky = 0
updated = false
def drop_mark(self, screen, cursorx, cursory):
        global markx, marky, updated
        Mark = pygame.image.load("Pin.Png").convert_alpha()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_z]:
            if updated == False:
                markx = cursorx
                marky = cursory
                updated = True
            screen.blit(Mark, (markx, marky))
```

Comment: This is very close to the answer I am looking for...However, it still doesn't resolve the issue of the mark disappearing when the Z button is not being pushed down.

Comment: Sorry, I took out the `else: updated = False` so it should work now. Just add that wherever you want to make it go away

Comment: Interestingly, adding else: self.markUpdated = False screen.blit(Mark, (self.markx, self.marky)), seemed to do the trick, as the marker only fell in the place where I pressed Z on.

Answer (score 1):

`WorldMapCursor` is an instance of the class `cursor`. You don't need the `cursorx` and `cursory` argument at all, because `WorldMapCursor` has the attributes `x` and `y` and you can access them by `self.x` and `self.y` in any instance method:
(See [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects), 
[Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) and [instance attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects))

```py
def drop_mark(self, screen):
        Mark = pygame.image.load("Pin.Png").convert_alpha()
        screen.blit(Mark, (self.x, self.y))
```

Move the cursor when <kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed:

```py
WorldMapCursor = cursor(CursorSprite, 0, 0)
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return

        createScreen(screen)
        WorldMapCursor.render(screen)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_z]:
            WorldMapCursor.move_right()
            WorldMapCursor.move_left()
            WorldMapCursor.move_down()
            WorldMapCursor.move_up()
        WorldMapCursor.drop_mark(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```